# How to get particular parameter value from json using ng-repeat in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm having JSON array. I need to get particular parameter value using ng-repeat in angularjs. I tried using filters and other ways but i didn't got values.

Here is my JSON

```
{
    "UserId":0,
    "Name":null,
    "ResponseStatus":null,
    "Category":[{
        "Id":0,
        "CategoryName":"Category 1",
        "Property":0,
        "SubCategory":{
            "SubCatId":"5600",
            "SubCatName":"Sub1"
        }
    }]
}
```

When i used 
`<p data-ng-repeat="(key,data) in input.model.Category[0].SubCategory">{{key}} :{{data}}</p>` It giving result like this.

```
<p>SubCatId :5600</p>
<p>SubCatName :Sub1</p>
```

But i want only `SubCatId :5600` using ng-repeat because i want to display this two values in different place.

Comment: Don't use a repeater. `<p>SubCatId :{{input.model.Category[0].SubCategory.SubCatId}}</p>`

Answer (score 0):

Why using an ng-repeat if you only want to show one element (Category at position 0 and/or subCatId) ?

If you only want to show the SubCatId of the SubCategory of the first Category, this simple syntax should work :

```
<p ng-model="input.model.Category[0].SubCategory.SubCatId"></p>
```

The only multi-valuable element in your JSON is Category, so if you want to show all the Category[x].SubCategory.SubCatId, the following syntax should do the job :

```
<p ng-repeat="category in input.model.Category">SubCatId :{{ category.SubCategory.SubCatId }}</p>
```

Comment: I doubt you want `ng-model`. More likely `ng-bind`